# converting uri to string in c#

Tags: c#, uri

I have this code:

```
   public static string FindRelativePath(string basePatrh, string targetPath)
    {
        Func<FileSystemInfo, string> getFullName = delegate(FileSystemInfo path)
            {
                string fullName = path.FullName;

                if (path is DirectoryInfo)
                {
                    if (fullName[fullName.Length - 1] != Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
                    {
                        fullName += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
                    }
                }

                return fullName;
            };

        string basePatrhFullName = getFullName(new DirectoryInfo(basePatrh));
        string targetPathFullName = getFullName(new DirectoryInfo(targetPath));

        Uri basePatrhUri = new Uri(basePatrhFullName);
        Uri targetPathUri = new Uri(targetPathFullName);
        Uri relativeUri = basePatrhUri.MakeRelativeUri(targetPathUri);

        return relativeUri.ToString().Replace('/', '\\');
    }
```

This code convert a path to a relative path compared to another path. For example:

```
   FindRelativePath("c:\test","C;\test\dir1\dir2")
```

would return
     dir1\dir2

The code works well but if there is space in path for example:

```
  FindRelativePath("c:\test","C;\test\dir1\dir 2")
```

it returns wrong string:

```
dir1\dir%202
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string FindRelativePath(string basePath, string targetPath)
{
           return Uri.UnescapeDataString(
                basePath.MakeRelativeUri(targetPath)
                    .ToString()
                    .Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
                );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Uri.UnescapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx) that is reverse function of [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

the string that is returned is not wrong %20 is representing the space between `dir` `2`

Answer (score 0):

"%20" is the escaped encoding for the US-ASCII space character 
So you have to Unescape it like Uri.UnescapeDataString